# Magento2 get items added to cart

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to make my own cart design.. So can anyone please help to get all items added to the cart.

Comment: Are you want to change desing at checkout/cart page or want to call cart item at any other place?

Comment: want to call cart item to other place with my custom design

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the REST API, Magento 2 has two different sets of routes, one for logged-in users and one for guest users.

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

(The logged-in user routes start with "quoteCart" and the guest user routes start with "quoteGuestCart".)

You can call the API using:

```
[GET] {base URL}/rest/V1/carts/mine
```

or for guest users:

```
[GET] {base URL}/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items
```

---

**Note**: you will need to get the cart id from a separate call if you want to use the guest cart route.  There is no way to combine these calls that I know of.  That call is:

```
[POST] {base URL}/rest/V1/guest-carts
```